# Is it possible to set LtpaToken2 cookie in websphere application?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, cookies, websphere, jsessionid

I hit REST url and get `JSESSIONID` and `LtpaTOken2`.

I want to authenticate the user using `LtpaToken2` before or after redirecting to URL (WebSphere server application) using Javascript (running on JSP page Tomcat server), I even made the change in server, Disable the `HttpOnly` cookie, but still, it removes from `JSESSIONID` cookie only not from the `LtpaToken2` cookie.

Or

Is there any way I can achieve this or what prerequisites do I need (some session ID or any cookie or server level change).

Comment: Reading this I am having trouble understanding what it is you really want to do. Do you want to authenticate a user towards a WAS server and then use the LtpaToken2 cookie for subsequent requests? Or are you already logged in and want to reuse an existing cookie?

Comment: Got the Idea how to do it , I will have to implement CORS in my web phere server.